# Windows application to type exotic characters like Android?

Tags: windows, keyboard

I found nothing with "windows accents android".

I'm looking for a Windows application that lets users type exotic characters (éà©…Éœß, etc.) à la Android:

[image: https://s17.postimg.cc/7kb6oihj3/Android.Huawei.EMUI.accents.png]

I checked the following, but found them wanting:

- https://github.com/samhocevar/wincompose
- https://keyxpat.com/en/how
- Wizkey http://antibody-software.com/web/
- http://www.holdkey.eu/

Is there a Windows application that does this?

Thank you.

--

Edit:

Ideally, I'd rather a solution that creates a brand new keyboard layout like Windows does to switch between different langugages, instead of having to use awkward multi-key combos to type a character, eg. AltGr + ' + e to get "é". I don't care if it's open- or closed-source.

At this point, it seems like the solution is to use one of the tools below:

- Microsoft Keyboard Layout Creator (MSKLC)
- Portable Keyboard Layout (PKL)
- KbdEdit
- AutoHotKey (need to double-check)

Comment: There are dozens of alternative keyboards.  The Neo keyboard layout is supposed to  be one for as many languages as possible but basically you have to pick a target language because you are tying on a keyboard(unless I misunderstood your question and you are referring to Windows Tablets).

Comment: Thanks for the input. I hadn't thought about that solution. Do you know of an easy way to keep my QWERTY keyboard layout for common use, and add a second layer that I could activate and would contain the exotic characters I often use?

Comment: AltGr is the key used in other languages.  Download microsoft creator.

Comment: Thx. If possible, I'd rather have direct access to keys instead of using a combination (CTRL, SHIFT, ALT, AltGr.) I'll read up on Microsoft Keyboard Layout Creator.

Comment: Then use autohotkey for that.  Autohotkey can do just about anything.  It's what I use.

Comment: another solution is to change the caps lock behavior and then use caps lock as a toggle between 2 layouts.  I have done this but capital letters + caps lock can get tricky.

Comment: Have you thought about giving feedback to one or more of the Open Source tools you mention on why you find it unusable to see if you & the author(s) can't come up with something better?

Comment: I wrote WinCompose for that specific purpose; can you be more specific about what it lacks? I’d be willing to add features if they fall into the scope of the software.

Comment: Steve Barnes > Have you thought about giving feedback to one or more of the Open Source tools you mention on why you find it unusable to see if you & the author(s) can't come up with something better?

REPLY I don't care about open-source solutions specifically: If there's a much better commercial/closed source solution, I'm perfectly fine with the latter.

Comment: sam hocevar > I wrote WinCompose for that specific purpose; can you be more specific about what it lacks? I’d be willing to add features if they fall into the scope of the software

REPLY Yes: If avoidable, I'd rather have a full, customized keyboard layout, than having to use combos, ie. CTRL/SHIFT/ALT + one or two more keys.

https://github.com/samhocevar/wincompose

Comment: William > another solution is to change the caps lock behavior and then use caps lock as a toggle between 2 layouts. I have done this but capital letters + caps lock can get tricky. REPLY Good idead, but the question is: How to build that other layout to begin with?

Comment: Re: Steve Barnes' comment: You still have not responded to that. If you write a question here specifying what you **don't** want you have to tell us why. Do not waste the time of people here by giving them vague criteria.

Comment: Edited my question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

There is a company specializing for many years in keyboards, mainly for Windows:

https://keyman.com/

On their website, you will find many ready-made solutions. And you will find tools like their "Keyman Developer" that will give you a lot of work but total control over your keyboard layouts and behaviour:

https://keyman.com/developer/

I have used this in the past, and it was too much work, but good product. I am known to work with SIL, who abtained the Keyman company a few years ago (or something like that), but I am not afiliated and not involved in any way.

Presently we are still using MSKLC, which is no longer supported, but there are good help questions/answers over on Super User on how to get that going on a Windows 10 machine.

Answer (score 0):

When I see your screenshot, I'm thinking that the [Keyxpat](https://keyxpat.com) tool you mention does exactly what you're looking for. Can you tell why you think it's inadequate?
Note: I'm Keyxpat author.

[image]

After second thought, it seems you may want to see a solution that works visually, i.e. that shows the characters that can be chosen from a set. If yes, then know that the current version in development has such a visual aid. If you want to try it, please let me know.